# Laravel eloquent multiple search filters

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Given the query below, how do you add more where/add (mysql) fields conditions, up to 4 fields?

```
$query = Profile::select('field1', field2', 'field3, 'field4', DB::raw('SUM(likes.like) AS total'))
        ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('likes', 'likes.profile_id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
        ->whereNotNull('users.id')
        ->groupBy('users.id')
        ->orderBy('users.last_login_at', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

I've tried adding like below, which results in 405 errors:

```
    $query = Profile::select('field1', field2', 'field3, 'field4', DB::raw('SUM(likes.like) AS total'))
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('likes', 'likes.profile_id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
            ->whereNotNull('users.id');

    if ($field1 != 'condition') {    
        $query->where('profiles.field1', $field1)
    }
            $query->groupBy('users.id')
            ->orderBy('users.last_login_at', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in your select statement .

```
 $query = Profile::select('field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', "DB::raw('SUM(likes.like) AS total')")
        ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
        ->leftJoin('likes', 'likes.profile_id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
        ->where('users.id', "!=", '');

if ($field1 != 'condition') {    
   $query = $query->where('profiles.field1', $field1)
}
        $query = $query->groupBy('users.id')
        ->orderBy('users.last_login_at', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

Assign the appended value to same variable `$query`